# Python: How to process pasted text from the clipboard?

Tags: python, string

I'm processing a string like this:

```
    scrpt = "\tFrame\tX pixels\tY pixels\r\n\t2\t615.5\t334.5\r\n\t3\t615.885\t334.136\r\n\t4\t615.937\t334.087\r\n\t5\t615.917\t334.106\r\n\t6\t615.892\t334.129\r\n\t7\t615.905\t334.117\r\n\t8\t615.767\t334.246\r\n\t9\t615.546\t334.456\r\n\t10\t615.352\t334.643\r\n\r\n"

    infile = StringIO(scrpt)
    #pretend infile was just a regular file...

    r = csv.DictReader(infile, dialect=csv.Sniffer().sniff(infile.read(1000)))
    infile.seek(0)

    Frame, Xco, Yco = [],[],[]
    for row in r:
        Frame.append(row['Frame'])
        Xco.append(row['X pixels'])
        Yco.append(row['Y pixels'])
```

This works fine.  I get the string variable 'scrpt' sorted nicely into the the variables 'Frame', 'Xco', and 'Yco'

Now if I do this:

```
print(scrpt)
```

I see things neatly laid out in tabbed columns like this:

```
Frame   X pixels    Y pixels

2   615.5   334.5
3   615.885 334.136
4   615.937 334.087
5   615.917 334.106
6   615.892 334.129
7   615.905 334.117
8   615.767 334.246
9   615.546 334.456
10  615.352 334.643
```

But if I have the same string pasted from the clipboard and try to process it it doesn't work.
In this case, if I print it like this:

```
print(scrpt)
```

I see:

```
\tFrame\tX pixels\tY pixels\r\n\t2\t615.5\t334.5\r\n\t3\t615.885\t334.136\r\n\t4\t615.937\t334.087\r\n\t5\t615.917\t334.106\r\n\t6\t615.892\t334.129\r\n\t7\t615.905\t334.117\r\n\t8\t615.767\t334.246\r\n\t9\t615.546\t334.456\r\n\t10\t615.352\t334.643\r\n\r\n
```

Then when I go to process it the csv module won't sort it out.

What am I doing wrong?
It looks like I'm using the same data in both cases but something is different.

Comment: Are you sure your clipboard has tab characters, not literal backslashes followed by `t`s? (For example, if you copy and paste the string from the first line of your source code, you'll get backslashes and `t`s, not tabs.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your clipboard has literal backslash and `t` characters, not tab characters. For example, if you just copy from the first line of your source, that's exactly what you'll get.

In other words, it's as if you did this:

```
scrpt = r"\tFrame\tX pixels\tY pixels\r\n\t2\t615.5\t334.5\r\n\t3\t615.885\t334.136\r\n\t4\t615.937\t334.087\r\n\t5\t615.917\t334.106\r\n\t6\t615.892\t334.129\r\n\t7\t615.905\t334.117\r\n\t8\t615.767\t334.246\r\n\t9\t615.546\t334.456\r\n\t10\t615.352\t334.643\r\n\r\n"
```

… or, equivalently:

```
scrpt = "\\tFrame\\tX pixels\\tY pixels\\r\\n\\t2\\t615.5\\t334.5\\r\\n\\t3\\t615.885\\t334.136\\r\\n\\t4\\t615.937\\t334.087\\r\\n\\t5\\t615.917\\t334.106\\r\\n\\t6\\t615.892\\t334.129\\r\\n\\t7\\t615.905\\t334.117\\r\\n\\t8\\t615.767\\t334.246\\r\\n\\t9\\t615.546\\t334.456\\r\\n\\t10\\t615.352\\t334.643\\r\\n\\r\\n"
```

If that's the problem, the fix is pretty easy:

```
scrpt = scrpt.decode('string_escape')
```

Or, in 3.x (where you can't call `decode` on a `str`):

```
script = codecs.decode(script, 'unicode_escape')
```

The `unicode_escape` codec is described in the list of [Standard Encodings](http://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) in the `codecs` module. It's defined as:

> Produce a string that is suitable as Unicode literal in Python source code

In other words, if you `encode` with this codec, it will replace each non-printing Unicode character with an escape sequence that you can type into your source code. If you've got a tab character, it'll replace that with a backslash character and a `t`.

You want to do the exact reverse of that: you've got a string you copied out of source code, with source-code-style escape sequences, and you want to interpret it the same way the Python interpreter does. So, you just `decode` with the same codec. If you've got a backslash followed by a `t`, it'll replace them with a tab character.

It's worth playing with this in the interactive interpreter (remember to keep the `repr` and `str` representations straight while doing so!) until you get it.

Comment: That's the answer: scrpt = codecs.decode(scrpt, 'unicode_escape').  Could you explain briefly why this works? Is it replacing the '\t' with tabs?

Comment: I'm new to 'Stack Overflow'.  Are we supposed to mark questions 'solved' like on other forums?

Comment: @terrachild: You don't do anything to the _question_; you click the check mark to accept one of the _answers_.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  That saved me a lot of time.